# how to reconnect Socket and Peerjs on internet restore in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, peerjs

I am using Socketio and peerjs for video chat applicaiton it works fine but when internet is lost and on restore it doesn't connect to server again, can someone guide me what i am missing.Thank in advance

```
const initPeerJsConnection = async () => {
    const PeerJs = (await import('peerjs')).default
    const peerConfig =
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NODE_ENV === 'local'
        ? {} // Local environment configuration
        : {
            config: {
              iceServers: [
                { urls: 'stun:stun-call.test.app' }, // Replace with your STUN server
                {
                  urls: 'turn:turn-call.test.app',
                  username: 'test',
                  credential: 'test' // Use the turnSecret as the credential
                }
              ]
            }
          }

    const peerInstance = new PeerJs(peerConfig)
    await peerInstance.on('open', userId => {
      setPeer(peerInstance)
    })
  }

  const initSocketConnection = async () => {
    const socketInstance = io(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL_SOCKET_IO, {
      reconnection: true, // Enable reconnection
      reconnectionAttempts: 5, // Number of reconnection attempts
      reconnectionDelay: 2000, // Initial reconnection delay in milliseconds
      reconnectionDelayMax: 5000, // Maximum reconnection delay
      timeout: 10000 // Connection timeout (in milliseconds)
    })
    socketInstance.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('connect socket');
    })

    socketInstance.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('disconnect socket');
    })

    socketInstance.on('reconnect', (attemptNumber) => {
      console.log('reconnect socket', attemptNumber);
    });

    socketInstance.on('user-disconnected', (userId, roomId) => {
      removeRemoteVideo(userId, roomId)
    });

    socketInstance.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error('Socket error:', error);
    });

  }
```

And socket reconnect event is not trigger in any condition.